# Split the string and display the result with checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a array of 3 items( values 1, 2 and 3) in abc and I want to display the same in my html with 3 checkboxes and each having one value.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function populate(demo) {


            var abc = [1,2,3];
       var s1 = document.getElementById(demo);
    }

    for (var option in abc) {
        if (abc.hasOwnProperty(option)) {
            var pair = abc[option];
            var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
            checkbox.type = "checkbox";
            checkbox.name = pair;
            checkbox.value = pair;
            abc.appendChild(checkbox);

            var label = document.createElement('label')
            label.htmlFor = pair;
            label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(pair));

            s1.appendChild(label);
            s1.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));    
        }
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
  Show checkboxes
<div id="demo" onload="populate('demo')"></div>

</body>
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/7n9w6kfm/1/

but in HTML it is displayed as **1,2,3** how can I display them with 3 checkboxes with values 1,2 and 3

Comment: A simple start would be to research ow to create new elements and how to set properties of them. it really doesn't look much effort has been put into this so far. Also need to clarify string vs array since you mentioned both

Comment: Your array is incorrect. You will get the following error in the browser console **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number** You array should look like this `var abc=[1,2,3];` Can you also display your attempt of creating the checkboxes?

Comment: I am actually just explaining you the issue, I am getting value in this x from controller and the values are 1,2,3 only , I ll edit my question and change it to [1,2,3]. thanks @NewToJS

Comment: The issue is you don't know how to create the checkboxes but to get help on stack overflow you must have some attempt of this yourself. We don't do all the work for you. *some do* but to get my help i need to know you're willing to at least try and help yourself before you copy/paste answers and feel you will read the comments and understand the answer before using it. I'm more than happy to help but you have to help yourself first.

Comment: no no I am interested in trying myself. just give a direction in which I can start from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't have any attempt to create the element but you are interested in how to create an element I will post this as an answer.

You can use `document.createElement()` [Click here for documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp)

> If you assign document.createElement() to a variable you can use that variable to apply attributes within javascript
>   `document.createElement("`**[Type Of Element]**`");`

Example: `document.createElement("div");` will create a div element.

Assign to a variable (NewDiv): `var NewDiv=`*document.createElement("div");*

Now you can apply other attributes as shown below.

```
var NewDiv= document.createElement('div');
NewDiv.setAttribute('id','SomeRandomID');
NewDiv.setAttribute('class','SomeClass');
document.body.appendChild(NewDiv);
```

If you want to insert the new element to a specific element/div/span you can do so using

```
var target=document.getElementById('ElementID');
target.appendChild(NewDiv);
```

I hope this helps you, if you have any problems understanding this let me know and I will update the answer to explain in more detail.

> **Additional Information:** this will create multiple elements if you place this into a for loop [Click here for documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp)

Happy coding!

> **Changes to your source code below**

```js
function populate() {
/*-------------^^Demo^^ not needed, you have the element by ID below.*/
var abc = [1,2,3];
var s1 = document.getElementById('demo');
    for (var option in abc) {
      if (abc.hasOwnProperty(option)) {
            var pair = abc[option];
            var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
            checkbox.type = "checkbox";
            checkbox.name = pair;
            checkbox.value = pair;
            s1.appendChild(checkbox);
/*----------^^ Change to s1, abc is an array, not an element--------*/
            var label = document.createElement('label')
            label.htmlFor = pair;
            label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(pair));
            s1.appendChild(label);
            s1.appendChild(document.createElement("br")); 
            }   
    }
}
window.onload=populate;
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

If you want to run function onload you need to apply onload="" to the body tag or use `window.onload=FunctionName` in javascript.

Comment: edited my question. I tried learning few things but its still not working.

Comment: Yes, i will add to my answer now, give me a few moments.

Comment: @PSDebugger Updated, I hope that's what you are looking for. If you have any more problems with this just leave a comment and I will get back to you as soon as I can. Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you sooo much. Let me add this to my code and test,

Comment: Make sure all is working as intended, if so and this post answers your question please make sure you mark your question as answered. This will help others who face the same problem find answers much easier.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72620/discussion-between-psdebugger-and-newtojs).

Comment: can we give a unique id to the checkboxes created at runtime ?

Comment: Yes you can, in my answer it shows you how to set attributes `.setAttribute('id','SomeRandomID');` if you don't know how to create a random/unique id then I can only recommend you research online, if you cannot find anything then it would mean submitting a new question on how to generate random but unique id's.